# Locking a Resource and generating Time Stamps according to lock time

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, critical-section, trusted-timestamp

Suppose that I would like to implement a synchronization primitive which generates a time stamp that is going to be used in a synchronization protocol. The time stamp would be such, that for a given *key* used to lock a *resource*, no two threads would be able to obtain the same time stamp value.

A possible implementation of the latter specification would be:

```
namespace InfinityLabs.PowersInfinity.BCL.Synchronization
{

public static class TimeStampMonitor
{
    private static readonly IDictionary<object, long> TimeStamps;

    static TimeStampMonitor()
    {
        TimeStamps = new Dictionary<object, long>();
    }

    #region API

    public static long Enter(object key)
    {
        var lockTaken = false;

        Monitor.Enter(key, ref lockTaken);

        ThrowIfLockNotAcquired(key, lockTaken);

        var timeStamp = GetCurrentTimeStamp();

        Thread.Sleep(1);

        TimeStamps.Add(key, timeStamp);

        return timeStamp;
    }

    public static void Exit(object key)
    {
        var lockTaken = false;

        Monitor.Enter(key, ref lockTaken);

        try
        {
            ThrowIfInvalidKey(key);
            TimeStamps.Remove(key);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (lockTaken)
                Monitor.Exit(key);
        }
    }

    public static long GetTimeStampOrThrow(object key)
    {
        TryEnterOrThrow(key);

        var timeStamp = GetTimeStamp(key);
        return timeStamp;
    }

    public static void TryEnterOrThrow(object key)
    {
        var lockTaken = false;

        try
        {
            Monitor.Enter(key, ref lockTaken);

            ThrowIfLockNotAcquired(key, lockTaken);
            ThrowIfInvalidKey(key);
        }
        catch (SynchronizationException)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            if(lockTaken)
                Monitor.Exit(key);

            throw;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Time Stamping

    private static long GetCurrentTimeStamp()
    {
        var timeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToUnixTime();
        return timeStamp;
    }

    private static long GetTimeStamp(object key)
    {
        var timeStamp = TimeStamps[key];
        return timeStamp;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Validation

    private static void ThrowIfInvalidKey(object key, [CallerMemberName] string methodName = null)
    {
        if (!TimeStamps.ContainsKey(key))
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Must invoke '{nameof(Enter)}' prior to invoking '{methodName}'. Key: '{key}'");
    }

    private static void ThrowIfLockNotAcquired(object key, bool lockTaken)
    {
        if (!lockTaken)
            throw new SynchronizationException($"Unable to acquire lock for key '{key}'");
    }
    #endregion
}
}
```

Mind that the two API methods *TryEnterOrThrow* and *GetTimeStampOrThrow* are intended to be used by consuming classes as guard methods which disallow poorly written code to break the critical section's atomicity. The latter method also returns a previously acquired time stamp value for a given key. The time stamp is maintained so long that its owner did not exit the critical section.

I have been running all possible scenarios through my mind, and I cant seem to break it- not only atomically, but by trying to misuse it.
I guess my question is, since this is one of my very few attempts at writing synchronization primitives- is this code fool proof and does it provide atomicity?

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Just looking through this is not going to work: sleeping under lock usually is superslow

Comment: one issue here ... `DateTime.Now` is updated within an interval of some ms only, as this is no high precision implementation like `TimeSpan` is.

Comment: @Lol4t0 : what would you reccomend?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair I will consider that! thanks!

Comment: It depends on the task actually. May be just an integer initialized with 0 and incrementing on 1 on every call will be ok (so it will work like _logical_ timestamp). But I have to understand what you are going to achieve first (and most probably  I could not provide best answer in C# land anyway)

Comment: @Lol4t0 I am syncing db tables with client devices.. since each client stores the time stamp issued by the server and receives info according to that time stamp on the next sync session, I can't risk the timestamp resetting. logical timestamps do hold that risk in the grand scheme of things. anyway - the answer below suffices and even does so without locking. Nonetheless, if you have any ideas, I am always willing to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14369695/224370

You can create a unique timestamp without locking. Code below.

Your question differs slightly in that you want a unique timestamp per key, but if you have a globally unique timestamp then you automatically have a unique timestamp per key without any extra effort. So I don't think you really need a dictionary for this:

```
public class HiResDateTime
{
   private static long lastTimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
   public static long UtcNowTicks
   {
       get
       {
           long original, newValue;
           do
           {
               original = lastTimeStamp;
               long now = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
               newValue = Math.Max(now, original + 1);
           } while (Interlocked.CompareExchange
                        (ref lastTimeStamp, newValue, original) != original);

           return newValue;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I have to lock since I am using the time stamp in a synchronization protocol, per some key which has to block threads trying to work with the resource..

Comment: @EyalPerry please read the documentation on `Interlocked`. only one thread can compare and exchange the value, hence it is lock-free through enforced CPU instruction ordering.

Comment: Just as a aide-note: `DateTime.Now` is not high-precision timed, as its internal value is only updated every 35ms or so.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair noted, sir !