# Xamarin System.Thread.Timer

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross, system.timers.timer

I am trying to add System.Threading.Timer from nuget packages since it's not already in my core project. When I do I get the following error.

You are trying to install this package ointo a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=4.5,Profile78', but the package does not contain assembly reference or content files that are compatible with that framework.

Not sure how to resolve this issue. Could use some help on this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: System.Threading.Timer doesn't have a PCL compatible binary.

Comment: So if I want to use a timer based task in PCL?

Comment: This is a dup: There are several Q/A here concerning the same thing, try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30399796/xamarin-forms-error-using-system-timers-and-sysem-json

Comment: Yeah I found a similar solution, not the one you recommended though. However I will mark this as a dup regardless so people can be encouraged to look for other answers.