# System.Timer missing from Xamarin PCL

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, cross-platform

I am building a Xamarin cross platform app targeting IOS Android and Windows Phone 8.1 using .Net 4.5.1. When I try to reference System.Timers in the PCL project, it is not there. How do I fix this?

Comment: This 'behavior' matches and follows what is actually available in 4.5.1 portable. I believe it is now in 4.5.2, but that does not help you now on Xamarin/iOS-Andriod. See for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555049/timer-in-portable-library

Comment: Also discussed and replied to by Xamarin on their forums: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17227/timer-in-portable-class-library

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use : Device.StartTimer

Syntax :

```
public static void StartTimer (TimeSpan interval, Func<bool> callback)
```

Examples : increment number every 1 seconds for 1 minutes

```
int number = 0;
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),() => {
    number++;
    if(number <= 60) 
    {
        return true; //continue
    }
    return false ; //not continue

});
```

Examples : wait for 5 seconds to run function one time

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),() => {
    DoSomething();
    return false ; //not continue
});
```

Comment: **Device.StartTimer** is just part of **Xamarin.Forms** and it is not compatible with Xamarin Native Development's **Portable class library** or **Shared library**

Answer (score 5):

I noticed this the other day. Eventhough the class is in the API documentation [System.Threading.Timer Class](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Threading.Timer/)..Annoying.

Anyway I created my own Timer class, using `Task.Delay()`:

```
public class Timer
{

        private int _waitTime;
        public int WaitTime
        {
            get { return _waitTime; }
            set { _waitTime = value; }
        }

        private bool _isRunning;
        public bool IsRunning
        {
            get { return _isRunning; }
            set { _isRunning = value; }
        }

        public event EventHandler Elapsed;
        protected virtual void OnTimerElapsed()
        {
            if (Elapsed != null)
            {
                Elapsed(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }

        public Timer(int waitTime)
        {
            WaitTime = waitTime;
        }

        public async Task Start()
        {
            int seconds = 0;
            IsRunning = true;
            while (IsRunning)
            {
                if (seconds != 0 && seconds % WaitTime == 0)
                {
                    OnTimerElapsed();
                }
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                seconds++;
            }
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            IsRunning = false;
        }
}
```

Comment: `await Task.Delay(1000);`. Why 1000 and not WaitTime?

Comment: @AR89 Good spot, It could be refactored to use `WaitTime`. At the moment it cycles round every `second` `(Task.Delay(1000))` then every `seconds` compares its value to `WaitTime` to see if it needs to fire the `TimerElapsed` event

Comment: `await Task.Delay(1000);
 seconds++;
OnTimerElapsed();`

This would be a right refactor? (I'll test it, but I can't right now)