# C# - Xamarin Forms not working as intended with Timer class

Tags: c#, xml, timer

I'm making an app in Xamarin Forms and at a point I want a user to press a button that makes numbers pop up in order going 3 - 2 - 1 and then switching to a different form.

Here is what I have

```
int counter;



public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    counter = 3;
}

//The Button handler for the 
void StartClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        aTimer.Interval = 1000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    { 
        //Blah.IsVisible = true;
        if(counter == 3)
        {
            this.ThreeImage.IsVisible = true;
            counter--;
        }
        else if(counter == 2)
        {
            this.ThreeImage.IsVisible = false;
            this.TwoImage.IsVisible = true;
            counter--;
        }
        else if(counter == 1){
            this.TwoImage.IsVisible = false;
            this.OneImage.IsVisible = true;
            counter--;
        }
        else{
            NavigationPage page = new NavigationPage(new StartPage());
            App.Current.MainPage = page;
        }

    }
```

Where OneImage, TwoImage and ThreeImage are Image objects in my MainPage.xaml named appropriately and with "IsVisible" set to false.

What am i doing wrong? It doesn't appear as though any element I want is even flashing at all.

Comment: OnTimedEvent hits when you debug ?

Answer (score 0):

In PCL you need to start timer based on Device you cannot start directly from PCL. Before call timer set the device then call `Timer'.

here is example-https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/FrenchPressTimer,

[System.Timer missing from Xamarin PCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31107459/system-timer-missing-from-xamarin-pcl),
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer/