# How to create timer in C#?

Tags: c#, timer, xamarin.forms

I've tried using `System.windows.form` and `System.Timers.Timer` but both are not recognize by visual studio 2017 xamarin form. This made me unable to create `Timer time = new Timer(1000);`. How do we actually create and set the interval of a timer in C#? I need the full C# code of JavaScript `setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);` for xamarin form.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555049/timer-in-portable-library

Answer (score 1):

I think you can take a look to [StartTimer](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer/p/System.TimeSpan/System.Func%7BSystem.Boolean%7D/)

```
public static Void StartTimer (TimeSpan interval, Func<bool> callback)
```

interval

The interval between invocations of the callback.

callback

The action to run when the timer elapses.

**While the callback returns true, the timer will keep recurring.**

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Timer
{
    CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    public Task Wait(TimeSpan delay)
    {
        return Task.Delay(delay, _cts.Token);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _cts.Cancel();
    }
}
```

usage:

```
var t = new Timer();
await t.Wait(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this:

```
await Task.Delay(3000);

DisplayAlert("Hello", "", "OK");
```