# How do timers work in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer

I was coding a console application in C#, and my code was like this:

```
 while(true)
 {
 //do some stuff
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000)
 }
```

I noticed the memory usage of my application was about 14k while "sleeping".
But then I referenced System.Windows.Forms and used a timer instead and I noticed huge drop in memory usage.

My question is, what is the proper way of making something execute every few seconds without using that much memory?

Comment: Don't use `Thread.Sleep()` for timing purposes please. Its not accurate.

Comment: [Here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program.aspx) is an interesting atricle on Thread.Sleep, to add to what vanneto said, combining Thread.Sleep with a while(true) loop will also result in high CPU usage, compared to a timer

Comment: FWIW `Thread.Sleep` is actually very accurate compared to any of the timers in the BCL. My tests show that `Sleep` is accurate to ~1ms with a stddev of 0.08ms. `System.Threading.Timer` on the other hand is only accurate to ~14ms with a stddev of 0.6ms. Mileage will vary.

Comment: Also, `Sleep` will not cause high CPU. In fact, on my machine with a timeout of 1 or higher calling `Sleep` in a tight loop will yield ~0% CPU usage. `Sleep(0)`, of course, will consume ~100% CPU usage. There are reasons for this as `Sleep(0)` and `Sleep(1)` have special meaning.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx)

Add a method that will handle the `Elapsed` event and execute the code you want. In your case:

```
System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

_timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
_timer.Interval = 60000;
_timer.Enabled = true;

private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
   // add your code here
}
```

Here is a good post regarding the difference between the two `Timers`:

- [SO: System.Timers.Timer vs System.Threading.Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416803/system-timers-timer-vs-system-threading-timer)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `Timer` class.

There are multiple built-in timers ( `System.Timers.Timer`, `System.Threading.Timer`, `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` ,`System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer`) and it depends on the requirement which timer to use.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14296704/649524) answer to get and idea of where which timer should be used.

Following is an interesting read.
[Comparing the Timer Classes in the .NET Framework Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx)