# Create an extension method to do periodic work

Tags: c#, extension-methods, async-await, c#-5.0

I found a great way on how to do periodic work using the async/await pattern over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14297203/899260

Now what I'd like to do is to create an extension method so that I can do

```
someInstruction.DoPeriodic(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

Is that possible at all, and if, how would you do it?

**EDIT:**

So far, I refactored the code from the URL above into an extension method, but I don't know how to proceed from there

```
  public static class ExtensionMethods {
    public static async Task<T> DoPeriodic<T>(this Task<T> task, CancellationToken token, TimeSpan dueTime, TimeSpan interval) {
        // Initial wait time before we begin the periodic loop.
        if (dueTime > TimeSpan.Zero)
            await Task.Delay(dueTime, token);

        // Repeat this loop until cancelled.
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested) {


            // Wait to repeat again.
            if (interval > TimeSpan.Zero)
                await Task.Delay(interval, token);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to create an extension method? If yes, you have the answer, if no, you can use Google.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I've refactored the code from the link into an extension method, but I don't know how to proceed from there. See my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the "periodic work" code accessing any of the `someInstruction` public members? If not, it does not make much sense to use an extension method in the first place.

if it does, and assuming that `someInstruction` is an instance of `SomeClass`, you could do something like the following:

```
public static class SomeClassExtensions
{
    public static async Task DoPeriodicWorkAsync(
                                       this SomeClass someInstruction,
                                       TimeSpan dueTime, 
                                       TimeSpan interval, 
                                       CancellationToken token)
    {
        //Create and return the task here
    }
}
```

Of course you must pass `someInstruction` to the `Task` constructor as a parameter (there is a constructor overload that allows you to do that).

**UPDATE** based on comment by OP:

If you just want to have a reusable method for executing arbitrary code periodically, then an extension method is not what you need, but rather a simple utility class. Adapting the code from the link you provided, it would be something like this:

```
public static class PeriodicRunner
{
public static async Task DoPeriodicWorkAsync(
                                Action workToPerform,
                                TimeSpan dueTime, 
                                TimeSpan interval, 
                                CancellationToken token)
{
  // Initial wait time before we begin the periodic loop.
  if(dueTime > TimeSpan.Zero)
    await Task.Delay(dueTime, token);

  // Repeat this loop until cancelled.
  while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
  {
    workToPerform();

    // Wait to repeat again.
    if(interval > TimeSpan.Zero)
      await Task.Delay(interval, token);       
  }
}
}
```

Then you use it like this:

```
PeriodicRunner.DoPeriodicWorkAsync(MethodToRun, dueTime, interval, token);

void MethodToRun()
{
    //Code to run goes here
}
```

or with a simple lambda expression:

```
PeriodicRunner.DoPeriodicWorkAsync(() => { /*Put the code to run here */},
   dueTime, interval, token);
```

Comment: hm. my intention was like this: I'm reusing that code all over the place, and only the line with the comment "// TODO: Do some kind of work here. " changes. So i thought instead of copy and pasting that code all over the place, I would like to have some boilerplate code and just pass in the instructions. Hence the idea with the extension method.

Comment: thanks!!

btw "public static Task DoPeriodicWorkAsync" should be "public static async Task DoPeriodicWorkAsync" ;)

Comment: Very useful answer bu I got an exception cancelling it: `TaskCanceledException` after using `Cancel()` method on the `CancellationTokenSource.token` I pass to the method. How to propely handle the cancellation of the `PeriodicRunner`? thanks