# How to create periodic task

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have C# 2.0 codes that I am porting to C# 4.0. I want to make use of `System.Task` in place of the `System.ThreadPool.QueueueUserWorkItem`. I also want to make use of `System.Task` in place of `System.Threading.Timer`.

How do I create a periodic `System.Task`? I do not see anything on `System.Task` or `System.TaskFactory`.

Kind regards for consideration,

pKumara

Comment: What's wrong with a `Timer`? You can use the timer callback to start your new task if you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a Task based replacement for System.Threading.Timer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890915/is-there-a-task-based-replacement-for-system-threading-timer)

Answer (score 22):

Use Observable.Interval or Observable.Timer. Timer allows you to pass in a dueTime

e.q.

```
           // Repeat every 2 seconds.
        IObservable<long> observable = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

        // Token for cancelation
        CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();

        // Create task to execute.
        Action action = (() => Console.WriteLine("Action started at: {0}", DateTime.Now));
        Action resumeAction = (() => Console.WriteLine("Second action started at {0}", DateTime.Now));

        // Subscribe the obserable to the task on execution.
        observable.Subscribe(x => { Task task = new Task(action); task.Start();
                                      task.ContinueWith(c => resumeAction());
        }, source.Token);
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. I am trying to accept your answer but unknown error has occurred.

Comment: Strange, but glad it answered your question!

Comment: You have to add `Reactive Extensions - Query library` from a NuGet package in order to have Observable namespace available.

Answer (score 3):

You can try with [Observable.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.timer%28v=vs.103%29) which Returns an observable sequence of timer.