# Can I add in Thread.sleep() to address the rate limit exceeded error on Twitter?

Tags: twitter

To address the Rate Limit Exceeding issue in code, I am just wondering, can I do this?

```
do
    {
        Log.Info(this, string.Format("Fetching user timeline statuses for {0}", screenName));


            var twitterService = new TwitterService(_consumerKey, _consumerSecret);
            twitterService.AuthenticateWith(_accessToken, _accessTokenSecret);


            ListTweetsOnUserTimelineOptions listTweetsOnUserTimelineOptions =
                new ListTweetsOnUserTimelineOptions();
            listTweetsOnUserTimelineOptions.ScreenName = screenName;
            listTweetsOnUserTimelineOptions.IncludeRts = true;

            Thread.sleep(50000);

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error(this, string.Format("exception happened whille calling Twitter Service{0}", e.StackTrace));
        }

    } while (result.Count < count);
```

According to the API, the time is divided in to 15 minutes window now. So, by putting in a Thread.sleep() would that be OK? because Twitter documentation doesn't really provide any code example.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but I'd look for a more sophisticated task scheduling, like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14945407/253468

Also revisit the Twitter API docs, I think it's not one request you can send every 15 minutes. Divide the number of times you can request over 15 minutes to know how often you can run your scheduled task.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by divide the number of times you can request over 15 minutes? The API says 15 calls every 15 minute, or 180 calls every 15 minute. I mean if I go by 15 calls every 15 minutes, that means, I should sleep for 3600 seconds between each call right? if I go by 180 calls every 15 minutes , then that is 5 seconds between each call. Am I interpreting that correctly?

Comment: Yes,
15 calls/15 minutes = 1 call/minute => sleep 60 seconds = 60000 ms;   180 calls/15 minutes = 12 calls/minute => sleep 5 seconds = 5000 ms.

But the main point is to use `PeriodicTaskFactory.Start` or similar instead of `do/while`.