# Async Task how to return value back from a method

Tags: c#

```
CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

Task tasks = PeriodicTaskFactory.Start(() => LongRunningOperation(), intervalInMilliseconds: 1000, synchronous: false, cancelToken: cancellationTokenSource.Token);

int taskId = Task.WaitAny(tasks);
```

and my LongRunningOperation

```
private String LongRunningOperation()
{
...
return proj.Name;
}
```

but the problem is how to get value from `LongRunningOperation` method back in `Task`. Method `tasks.Results` not exists. And I want to get back the value from each Task.

I get PeriodicTaskFactory class from here

[Is there a Task based replacement for System.Threading.Timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890915/is-there-a-task-based-replacement-for-system-threading-timer)

Thank you

Comment: If `Start` returned a single `Task`, then you wouldn't be able to use `Task.WaitAny` on it. I think you meant that `Start` returns `Task[]`.

Comment: @dcastro "Start" return back "return Task.Factory.StartNew(mainAction, cancelToken, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Current);"

Comment: Then this line is wrong: `int taskId = Task.WaitAny(tasks);`. There is no `WaitAny` overload that accepts a single task.

Comment: Thank you. And what is then correct. The code you paste it in reply?

Comment: The code in my reply helps you get a result back. Don't you get a compile error with the code you posted? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: No code is working without any error. I want to run Task every x seconds and executing some data. This needs to be then returned back for further analyze. But important is that everything is working async. More tasks at the same time.

Comment: The line with `WaitAny` doesn't make any sense, but that's not your question. My answer shows you how to grab the result of the task returned by the `StartPeriodicTask`.

Comment: WaitAny is used that wait until one task is finished. Isn't that true?

Comment: No, `WaitAny` waits until one **of many** tasks is finished. Take a look at the msdn documentation, all overloads take an array of Tasks: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.waitany(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Task` has no return value; `Task<T>` does.

You have to modify the `PeriodicTaskFactory` code to return `Task<T>` instead, and then create `Task<string>` objects.
The method should also accept a `Func<T>` (has no arguments, returns T) instead of an `Action`, which has no return value.

```
public static Task<T> Start<T>(Func<T> func,
      int intervalInMilliseconds = Timeout.Infinite,
      int delayInMilliseconds = 0,
      int duration = Timeout.Infinite,
      int maxIterations = -1,
      bool synchronous = false,
      CancellationToken cancelToken = new CancellationToken(),
      TaskCreationOptions periodicTaskCreationOptions = TaskCreationOptions.None)
    {


Task<string> task = PeriodicTaskFactory.Start(LongRunningOperation, intervalInMilliseconds: 1000, synchronous: false, cancelToken: cancellationTokenSource.Token);

string result = task.Result;
```

Comment: can you just for info put back the code with Wait. And what should be in {...} in StartPeriodicTask

Comment: I'm sorry, but you'll have to modify the `Start` code yourself. I gave you the necessary hints: use Task<T> instead of Task, and Func<T> instead of Action.

Comment: Ok I will do it. Thanks for help.